# Tensorflow: dynamic_rnn under specific gpu device can't work, no supported kernel for GPU devices is available

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use dynamic_rnn under specific gpu device, but it raises errors as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sequence = [[1, 2],[2, 3, 5]]
def generator():
    for el in sequence:
        yield el

dataset = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(generator, tf.int32, tf.TensorShape([None]))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda seq: (seq, tf.size(seq)))
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(1, padded_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None]), tf.TensorShape([])), padding_values=(0, 0))
iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
seq, seq_len = iter.get_next()

embedding = tf.get_variable('embeddings', [10, 100])
cells = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(5)
emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, seq)

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):  # If I assign the gpu device, the codes below will raise errors
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cells, inputs=emb, sequence_length=seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iter.initializer)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    out = sess.run(outputs)
```

Errors:

```
Caused by op 'rnn/Assert/Assert', defined at:
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cells, inputs=emb, sequence_length=seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 622, in dynamic_rnn
    [_assert_has_shape(sequence_length, [batch_size])]):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 617, in _assert_has_shape
    packed_shape, " but saw shape: ", x_shape])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py", line 118, in wrapped
    return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 172, in Assert
    return gen_logging_ops._assert(condition, data, summarize, name="Assert")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 51, in _assert
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'rnn/Assert/Assert': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'

     [[Node: rnn/Assert/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], summarize=3, _device="/device:GPU:0"](rnn/All, rnn/Assert/Assert/data_0, rnn/stack, rnn/Assert/Assert/data_2, rnn/Shape_1)]]
```

If I don't use tf.device('/gpu:0'), then the codes can work well.
But for some reason I need to use it, e.g. multi-gpu support.
How should I resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the "soft placement" option for the session, that is, to ask TensorFlow to use the indicated device unless there is no kernel for it, in which case it would fallback to CPU:

```
# ...
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
    # ...
```

Another possibility is to pass instead a function to [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device), such that the GPU device is selected unless the given operation meets some condition (typically when it has some specific type, in this case `Assert`, although there might be other operations that you would need to exclude in the model):

```
def assign_device(op):
    if op.type != 'Assert':
        return '/gpu:0'
    else:
        return '/cpu:0'

# ...
with tf.device(assign_device):
    # ...
```